# After installing fire base in react native project ,showing Error status code 1

Tags: firebase, react-native

After installing firebase in project below error is showing.

Firebase installed by using following command: "npm install firebase --save"

Ran "npm start"

Command prompt  showing below error.Please look at the below image
[Command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMrCU.png)

Please look at the below log file

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qS7p1.png): [Log File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qS7p1.png)

Error is not only after installing firebase whenever i tried to install react-native-modal-dropdwon or react-navigation same error occurs

Comment: Your log file is a duplicate of your command prompt image.

Comment: Log file added,Please check and help me on this